# send reminder email for one time

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a list in sharepoint online that name is DOPI,
There is a **field that call Status**, it contains the two values: Draft & Manager
I want to send reminder email **just for one time** to the person who their **status is DRAFT**.

I create another list for send emails that name is: Admin email send, that means if create a new item in this list, 
workflow should be run and **send reminder email** to the users in DOPI list with the **DRAFT status.** just for **One time**

Can you give me the solution?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly: have another column to mark that an email has been sent.  In your workflow you need to check to see if that field has been already set before you send the email.  If it's already set, it won't send another email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Call HTTP Web Service" action to get the users in the DOPI list with the Draft status. Then send email for all users who are returned from the web service response.

There are two blogs for your reference:
[SharePoint 2013 - Understanding and Using the SharePoint 2013 REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx)
[Get Items from SharePoint list using Call HTTP Web Service Action (SharePoint Designer 2013)](https://zareensoomro.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-call-http-web-service-action-sharepoint-designer-2013/)